# Can anybody tell me why this won't work? I'm using the row.columnname format and getting an error

Tags: python, pandas

```
import codecademylib3
import pandas as pd

orders = pd.read_csv('shoefly.csv')

print(orders.head())

orders['salutation'] = orders.apply(lambda order: "Dear Mr. " + order.last_name if order.gender == 'male' else "Dear Mrs. " + order.last_name)
```

[image]

I am getting the following error:

> ‘Series’ object has no attribute ‘gender’”, ‘occurred at index id’

Comment: I don't understand what the png is. You have a print, but that won't print a png. Instead of whatever that png is supposed to be for, include a sample input file that we can use for test.

Answer (score 0):

[The default `axis` for `df.apply` is `0` (column-wise)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply).

You'll need to apply row-wise, so add `axis=1`.

```
orders['salutation'] = orders.apply(
    lambda order: "Dear Mr. " + order.last_name if order.gender == 'Male' else "Dear Mrs. " + order.last_name,
    axis=1,
)
```

or, a touch more shortly using f-strings,

```
orders['salutation'] = orders.apply(
    lambda order: f"Dear {'Mr' if order.gender == 'Male' else 'Mrs'}. {order.last_name}",
    axis=1,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

very simple, just add axis=1

```
orders['salutation'] = orders.apply(lambda order: "Dear Mr. " + order.last_name if order.gender == 'male' else "Dear Mrs. " + order.last_name, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the extra expense of using `.apply` you can use a mask to select male / female rows and do the operation across the entire table. In this example, a `Series` containing the salutations for just one gender is created on the right, and then `.loc` is used to apply that series to the like-indexed rows on the left.

```
import pandas as pd

orders = pd.read_csv('shoefly.csv')

print(orders.head())

is_male = orders['gender'] == 'male'
orders['salutation'] = ''
orders.loc[is_male, 'salutation'] = 'Dear Mr. ' + orders[is_male]['last_name']
orders.loc[~is_male, 'salutation'] = 'Dear Mrs. ' + orders[~is_male][ 'last_name']

print(orders.head())
```